# No se como hacer responsive un form login

Tags: html, css, login, responsive

### Como hacer un Login Responsive.

Hola, tengo un codigo de un ***login*** y un ***register*** que estoy haciendo como proyecto para iniciar sesion o para registrarse, pero me gustaria hacerlo **responsive** y que quede adaptable para *computadoras*, *tablets* y *celulares*. El problema es que no se como hacerlo, ya que quizas hay que cambiar parte del codigo, modificar o agregar. Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Así se ve en la ***web***:
[image: Web]

Así se ve en ***movil***:

[image: Movil]

**Me gustaría que en esta versión, la imagen desapareciera y solo quedara el login para ingresar el email y contraseña.**

- **Código HTML:**

  ```
   <body>
       <section class="container">
           <div class="content">

     <div class="text">Bienvenido</div>
           <div class="text">de nuevo!</div>
           </div>
           <div class="content-form">
               <div class="form-box login">
                   <form class="formulario">
                       <h3>Iniciar Sesion</h3>

                   <div class="input-box">
                       <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="entradas" placeholder="Email">
                   </div>

               <div class="input-box">
                   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="entradas" placeholder="Contraseña">
               </div>

               <div class="checkbox">
                   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
                   <label for="checkbox">Recordarme</label>
               </div>

               <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Iniciar Sesion">
               <p class="texto">¿No tenes una cuenta? Crea una <a href="registro.html">aquí</a>.</p>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
  ```

- **Código CSS:**

  ```
   *{
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           padding: 0;
           margin: 0;
           font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif ;
           text-decoration: none;
    }      

   :root{
       --box-color: #e98b60;
   }

   body{
       background-color:#e0e0e0 ;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       display: flex;
   }

   .container{
       width: 1100px;
       height: 600px;
       border-radius: 5px;
       padding: 40px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 15%;
       background: url('img.jpeg') no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
       background-position: center;
       box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #0000006e;
   }

   .container .content{
       /* position: absolute; */
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 58%;
       height: 100%;
       color: white;
       font-size: 60px;
       font-weight: 600;
       margin-top: 80px;
       flex-direction: column;
       display: flex;
       align-items: flex-start;
   }

   .container .content-form{
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       width: calc(100% - 58%);
       height: 100%;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
   }

   .content-form .form-box{
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
   }

   .form-box h3{
       font-size: 2.5rem;
       text-align: center;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
   }

   .form-box .input-box{
       position: relative;
       width: 19rem;
       height: 50px;
       border-radius: 5px;
       border: 1px solid #acacac;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
       padding: 0 0 0 25px;
   }

   .input-box input{
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       border: none;
       outline: none;
       background: transparent;
       font-size: 15px;
       color: black;
   }

   .btn{
       width: 100%;
       height: 45px;
       background-color: var(--box-color);
       color: #ffffff;
       border: none;
       outline: none;
       border-radius: 4px;
       font-size: 16px;
       margin-top: 15px;
       cursor: pointer;
       transition: 0.3s;
   }

   p{
       text-align: center;
       margin-top: 5px;
   }

   a{
       color: var(--box-color);
   }

   .checkbox{
       margin-top: 12px;
       outline: none;
       text-decoration: none;
   }
  ```

---

Answer (score 0):

Usa los *Media Queries*:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .content, .content-form {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
    } 

    .image-container {
        display: none; /* Oculta la imagen en pantallas pequeñas */
    }

    .form-box {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .form-box .input-box {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .btn {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Intenté con este codigo que me recomendaste, pero no me funciona, sigue igual. Ademas la clase image-container no existe en mi codigo. La imagen que tiene el login fue ingresada por css no por una etiqueta de img.